# Signalr to return content

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

What is the best extension point of self hosted signalr to add some code to return additional content (for example list of hub methods and it's models description), just like /signalr/hubs returns javascript with autogenerated proxies.

Comment: You could probably just write [Owin Middleware](http://chris.59north.com/post/2014/05/06/Understanding-OWIN-%E2%80%93-hosting-and-middleware.aspx) to serve your purpose.

Comment: Yes, i've done it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
app.Map("/api",
            builder =>
                builder.Run(context => Task.Run(() => 
                             context.Response.Write(
                                     HubApiInfoProvider.GetApiInfo()))));
```

Where HubApiInfoProvider.GetApiInfo() returns a plain text. It's simplified version of @halter73 solution.